# simplexml parsing in PHP

Tags: php, simplexml

I got the following using print_r() in php.

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [term] => hello world
            [scheme] => Organization
        )
)
```

How do I access the scheme node using php simplexml? I am having trouble working with the node @attributes because of the @ symbol

Answer (score 2):

You would access attributes using array notation like this:

```
$scheme = $obj['scheme'];
```

See [Basic SimpleXML Usage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) from the PHP manual page.  It shows accessing attributes as well as other things.

Answer (score 1):

If your object was assigned to a variable called $my_xml you could access those two attributes by $my_xml['term'] and $my_xml['scheme']. http://php.net has some good examples at http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Answer (score 0):

here you se how to access an object and an attribute with simplexml

```
$xml->object
$xml['attribute']
```

more basics under http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php